# how can pass height and width to the imagekit templatetag?

Tags: python, django, templatetags, python-class, django-imagekit

**views.py**

```
class imagess(ImageSpec):
    processors = [SmartResize(100,100)]
    format = 'JPEG'
    options = {'quality': 100}

register.generator('main:imagess', imagess)
```

**index.html**

```
{% generateimage 'main:imagess' source=source_file %}
```

*this generates a image of height 100 x 100*

how can pass/define a custom height and width for the generated image from the HTML file....like

```
{% generateimage 'main:imagess' source=source_file height=1080 width=720 %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add extra attributes and pass them in view function definition, you can use those parameters:

```
{% generateimage 'myapp:thumbnail' source=source_file height=1080 width=720 %}
```

**Views.py**

```
class imagess(ImageSpec, height, width):
    processors = [SmartResize(height, width)]
    format = 'JPEG'
    options = {'quality': 100}

register.generator('main:imagess', imagess)
```

Comment: no no!....i want to pass height and width to the class ( exists in views.py )...so by that I can crop the image with a custom height and width.

Comment: did you try > {% generateimage 'myapp:thumbnail' source=source_file height = 1080 %}, and in your view > class imagess(ImageSpec, height)?

Comment: @ShivaSankar it give error as ....height not defined